# Getting error while starting server in Aptana3, RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aptana3

I'm afraid that I have a bit silly question, but I wasn't able to solve this problem myself:

```
alex@ALFA:~/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/rails-test$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /home/alex/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/rails-test/config/initializers/session_
store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: => '_rails-test_session'
                              ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key: => '_rails-test_session'` is not valid Ruby. You can either do `key => value` or `key: value`, but they can't be combined.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby hash syntax was [updated in 1.9](http://www.strictlyuntyped.com/2010/12/new-ruby-19-hash-syntax.html). You can now create hashes like this:

```
hash = {
  foo: "bar",
  faz: "baz"
}
```

But you can still use the old 'hash rocket' style:

```
hash = {
  :foo => "bar",
  :faz => "baz"
}
```

In both implementations `foo` and `faz` are [symbols](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html).

Your problem is that `key: => '_rails-test_session'` is a franken-hash, you're trying to combin both styles of hash. Either use `key:` or `:key =>`.